# Find a matrix $A$ such that $B=AA^T$

Tags: linear-algebra, stochastic-processes

I'm trying to write a fokker-planck equation as an SDE. I know my diffusion matrix, $D(\mathbf{x})$, where $D = \frac{1}{2}\sigma \sigma^T$.

How can I find this sigma, to then use in the SDE?

Edit: I don't think the fokker-planck bit is relevant to the question, it's just there for context (unless someone comes along and suggests a better way of going about it, which would be much appreciated!)

Edit 2: I've seen another answer that gives the answer if the matrix is positive definite. However, the entries in my matrix can vary, and I think it's unlikely all the eigenvalues will remain positive

Comment: My first guess would be the using the singular value decomposition, and then just taking the square roots of the singular values. However I don't know if the SVD also works well in the real case.

Comment: I'll give that a go, thanks!

Comment: @celtschk Just to make sure I'm interpreting what you say correctly, this is what I've tried:

[U,S,V] = singular value decomposition of B (S is a matrix of the singular values).

Let sS = the square root of S.

Then A = U*sS*V.

However, this doesn't give me $AA^T = B$ (tested on the matrix B = [1 2; 3 4]).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**If the matrix $B$ is *not* positive semi-definite, then there is no such matrix $A$.**

For suppose that
$$
Bv = c v
$$
for some negative number $c$, and unit vector $v$, **and** suppose that such an $A$ exists. Then
\begin{align}
\langle Bv, v \rangle &= c < 0. 
\end{align}
But we can also say

\begin{align}
\langle Bv, v \rangle &= 
\langle AA^tv, v \rangle \\
&=(AA^tv)^t v  \\ 
&=(v^t A^t A) v  \\ 
&=(v^t A^t) (A v)  \\ 
&= \langle Av, Av \rangle \\
&= \| Av \|^2 \ge 0\\
\end{align}
which is a contradiction.

So: for the matrix $B$ to have a "square root" like $A$ **requires** that $B$ be positive semidefinite. By the way, since $AA^t$ is symmetric, it also requires that $B$ be symmetric.

Those other proofs you saw: they weren't just being stupid by requiring symmetric positive semi-definiteness. They were actually proving the strongest theorem possible.

For actually finding the matrix $A$, @celtschk's suggestion is spot-on. The reason it didn't work in your test case is that your input matrix, $B$, wasn't symmetric. When it IS symmatric, you get
$$
B = U D V^t
$$
but it'll turn out that $V$ is actually equal to $U$, and $U^t U = I$, so you get
\begin{align}
B &= U D U^t
\end{align}
at which point you can define $E = D^\frac12$, adn note that $E$ is diagonal so that $E^t = E$, and thus
\begin{align}
B 
&= U D U^t\\
&= U E^2 U^t\\
&= U E^t E U^t\\
&= U E^t I E U^t\\
&= U E^t (U^t U) E U^t\\
&= (U E^t U^t) (U E U^t)\\
&= S^t S
\end{align}
where $S = UEU^t$.

You can shove the factor of $\frac12$ in there wherever you'd like it.